# ANGULAR AND PHASER CE How call Angular function in Phaser CE update function

Tags: angular, function, phaser-framework

I need call a function that trow a modal created with NgbModal. In the **update()** function, managed by Phaser CE, When the condition is true, the app crash throwing this: **ERROR TypeError: this.gameOver is not a function** I've tested all. gameOver() function exit from class, but the modalService created in the constructor is undefined....

Someone can help me?

mi ts File:

```
@ViewChild('msgGameOver') public modalmsgGameOver:TemplateRef<any>;

constructor( public modalService: NgbModal, private router:Router, private storage:Storage, 
private endpoint:EndpointsService){}

ngOnInit(){
  
game = new Phaser.Game(
  window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight,
  Phaser.AUTO, 
  'garrioCatapulta',
  {preload: this.preload, create: this.create, update: this.update, render: this.render},
  true
);

that = Object.create(this.constructor.prototype);    
}

gameOver() {
this.msgGameOver = "lo sentimos, no has acertado la casilla ganadora"
this.headerGameOver="¡Has perdido!";
this.iconGameOver = "assets/error.svg";
this.modalService.open(this.modalmsgGameOver);
}

preload(){

  game.load.image('roca', 'assets/aislada.svg');
  game.load.image('rebote','assets/rebote.svg');
  game.load.image('catapulta-dispara','assets/componentes_juego_catapulta_disparo.svg');
  game.load.image('colina', 'assets/derecha.svg');
  game.load.image('castillo', 'assets/izquierda_castillo.svg');
  
}
create(){

  game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.EXACT_FIT;     
  game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;      
  game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;        

  game.scale.refresh();

  game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

  roca = game.add.sprite(200, 500, 'roca');
  castillo = game.add.sprite(0,350,'castillo');
  catapulta=game.add.sprite(300,525,'catapulta-dispara');
  
  colina = game.add.sprite(280,565,'colina');
  colina.alignIn(game.world.bounds, Phaser.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
  catapulta.alignTo(colina,Phaser.TOP_LEFT);
  roca.alignTo(catapulta,Phaser.TOP_RIGHT);

  game.physics.enable(roca, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  game.physics.enable(colina, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  game.physics.enable(catapulta, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  game.physics.enable(castillo, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

  obstaculos = game.add.group()
  obstaculos.enableBody = true;

  colina.body.immovable = true;
  castillo.body.immovable = true;

  colina.body.immovable = true;
  castillo.body.immovable = true;
  catapulta.body.immovable = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {

      var s = obstaculos.create(game.rnd.integerInRange(75, 270),game.rnd.integerInRange(250, 500), 'rebote');
      s.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
      s.body.immovable = true;
      s.body.bounce.set(0.2);
  }

}



update(){
  
  if(game.physics.arcade.collide(roca, obstaculos)){
    console.log("choca roca")
  }
  
  if(game.physics.arcade.collide(roca, castillo)){
    c++;
    if(c >= 20){
      roca.body.stop();
      console.log("A pis pos");
      game.paused=true;
      this.gameOver();
    }
  }

  if(game.physics.arcade.collide(roca, colina)){
    co++;
    if(co >= 20){
      roca.body.stop();
      console.log("A pis pos");
      game.paused=true;
      this.gameOver();
    }
  };

  if(roca.body.onFloor()){
    i++;
    if(i >= 20){
      roca.body.stop();
      console.log("A pis pos");
      game.paused=true;

      this.gameOver();
    }
  }

}

render() { 

}
```

}

Comment: you need to show more code, hard to tell if your dom is ready, or is it promise related. or is it to do with Phaser lifecycle. what does your this.modalService contain? is it ready to consume when create() is called or is it still being lazy loaded by angular? also what does your modalService.open do? is the modal DOM ready to be called by angular at the time when you call GameOver()?  or is it a promise waiting for modalmsgGameOver to be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

in gameOver(), rewrite :

*this.modalService.open(this.modalmsgGameOver);*

to

*that.modalService.open(this.modalmsgGameOver);*

Comment: appreciate for your contribution. when you are providing code, you can use code Sample, feature while editing in stackOverflow so that your code will appear to be best formatted than using italics. To use Code Sample, click {} icon in your editor by selecting the source code so that StackOverflow automatically detects and formats. Thanks.